# How do I drop a view from all databases on a server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to drop a specific view from most databases on a server. Pasted below is what I currently have. It completes successfully but it does not actually drop the view.

What am I missing, why would it not error but not actually drop the view? Also, When I run the exec statement in a specific database it does drop the view.

```
USE [Master]

DECLARE @DBname    VARCHAR (128);
DECLARE @NumDBs    INT;
DECLARE @Count     INT = 0;


DECLARE getDBs CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('DBName1','DBName2')
ORDER BY name;

SET @NumDBs = (SELECT COUNT(9) FROM sys.databases WHERE
name NOT IN ('DBName1','DBName2') )
;

OPEN getDBs
FETCH NEXT FROM getDBs
INTO @DBname;

WHILE (@Count < @NumDBs)
BEGIN

Exec('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM '+@DBname+'.sys.views 
                  WHERE object_id= OBJECT_ID(N''[ViewName]''))                                                    
DROP VIEW [ViewName]'
);

 SET @Count = @Count + 1;

FETCH NEXT FROM getDBs
INTO @DBname;
END;

CLOSE getDBs;
DEALLOCATE getDBs;
```

Comment: `..DROP VIEW ' +@DBname+ '.dbo.[ViewName]...` It should be 3-part name dbname.schemaname.objectname

Comment: I've tried that. I get the following error: 'DROP VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Comment: what about sp_MSForEachDB ?  or updating the cursor to set the context to the specific database with a 'USE database1'

Comment: Thanks Brad D! 

I added the Use [DBName] inside the exec and it worked. I'll add my updated EXEC to the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
'USE [?];if db_id()>4 and db_name() not in (''somedb'',''somedb1'') drop view viewname;'
```

Comment: 'DBName1','DBName2' should be excluded

Answer (score 1):

Powershell to the rescue!

```
push-location;
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
pop-location;

$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server 'yourServer';
foreach ($db in $s.Databases | where {$_.IsAccessible -eq $true}) {
    $v = $db.Views['ViewName'];
    if ($v -ne $null) {
        $v.Drop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exec('USE ' +@DBname+'; IF  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM sys.views 
                  WHERE object_id= OBJECT_ID(N''[ViewName]''))                                                    
DROP VIEW [ViewName]'
);
```

Comment: we apparently came up with the samething at the same time. Thanks Again!

Comment: Please don't post just code, explain it, so the OP can learn from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my original EXEC statement as pasted below and all worked as I needed.

```
Exec( 
    'Use ['+@DBName+'] ;
     IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '+@DBname+'.sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[ViewName]''))
        DROP VIEW [ViewName]'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything's fine with your database. Except that I would not use cursor there as it is absolutely redundant, try avoiding them at any cost and start thinking in a row-set based logic.

You can build your query dynamically just like that:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @SQL += N'
    USE ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ';
    IF OBJECT_ID(''[ViewName]'', ''V'') IS NOT NULL
        DROP VIEW [ViewName];'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] NOT IN ('DBName1','DBName2')
ORDER BY [name];

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

On my local instance it would generate such query:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
USE [master];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
USE [model];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
USE [msdb];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
USE [ReportServer];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
USE [ReportServerTempDB];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
USE [tempdb];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
USE [test];
IF OBJECT_ID('[ViewName]', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [ViewName];
```

Overall, solution suggested by [@TheGameiswar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2975396/thegameiswar) is the best one, it uses `sys.sp_MSforeachdb`, which is created for exactly such use cases.

Comment: I agree, both  @TheGameiswar and yours does also do the trick,. But I also need to create a new version of the view I'm dropping. So I will actually end up with 2 Exec statements, 1 to drop it and 1 to add.

Comment: @Bgonzales That's not very important. I'm trying to point out that you should avoid cursors, perhaps there's no performance impact on such commands, but it's better to teach yourself to avoid using cursors at all.